# Buscar primeira e última palavra de um registro

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um trecho do código que pega e o primeiro e último nome do usuário de uma tabela e armazena em uma outra tabela. Por exemplo.:

Tabela **usuarios**: Carlos Drummond de Andrade

Pego o Carlos Andrade e armazeno em uma outra tabela.: Tabela **usuarios_selecionados**

O sistema tem uma busca interna do qual faz a busca da primeira tabela **usuarios**, porém como eu faria para que essa busca fosse precisa, tendo na visualização do cliente apenas o primeiro e último nome? Tentei usar o LIKE.:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM tab_usuarios WHERE NomeUsuarios LIKE '%".$nomeBusca."%' ");
```

Mas não funcionou!

Comment: Você quer buscar ou extrair a primeira e ultima palavras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quiser pegar os usuários que tiverem o mesmo primeiro e o último nome, separe a *string* buscada e busque cada parte do nome.

### Exemplo:

```
$nome = "Carlos Andrade";
$nome = explode(" ",$nome);
$primeiroNome = $nome[0];
$ultimoNome = $nome[1];
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM tab_usuarios WHERE NomeUsuarios LIKE '{$primeiroNome}%'  AND  LIKE '%{$ultimoNome}'");
```

Dessa forma sua busca retornará todos os usuários que tenha o primeiro nome `Carlos` e o último nome `Andade`.

Comment: Eu acho que ele não quer buscar, mas sim obter o primeiro e ultimo nome.

Comment: Pois é estou em dúvida também, vamos aguardar pelo retorno dele.

Comment: Olá a todos.. mais ou menos isso.. rs rs... preciso buscar na primeira tabela usuarios o nome e sobrenome que foram armazenados na tabela usuarios_cadastrados. Por ex.: Na tabela usuarios tenho o usuario Carlos Drummond de Andrade, porém foi armazenado na tabela usuarios_selecionados apenas Carlos Andrade. Só que na busca interna, se o cliente digitar Drummond, não apareça Carlos Drummond de Andrade, já que a busca principal está sendo na tabela usuarios, porém somente se digitar Carlos ou Andrade.